# I want to assign values to an empty list

Tags: python

here I want to store the square root values of userDist in userDist list with this for loop like below:

```
  userDist = []
  for i in usersXcordd:
      userDist[i].append(math.sqrt((usersXcordd[i] - baseStationX)^2 + (usersYcordd[i] -  
         baseStationY)^2))
```

Comment: remove the `[i]` after `userDist`

Answer (score 1):

You can just append a value to a list instead of appending it to a value of the list. For example, the following code would work.

```py
userDist.append(value)
```

But the following would not work (unless `userDist[i]` itself is a list).

```py
userDist[i].append(value)
```

You can read more about the [`append`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp) method here.

---

### The complete code

The complete and working code should be as follows.

```py
userDist = []

for i in usersXcordd:
    value = math.sqrt((usersXcordd[i] - baseStationX)**2 + \
                      (usersYcordd[i] - baseStationY)**2)
    userDist.append(value)
```

Comment: Good solution to a vague question. Upvoted yours, hope you upvote mine too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead(assuming Y coordinate list and X Xoordinate List have same length):

```
userDist = []
for j,i in enumerate(usersXcordd):
  userDist.append(((i - baseStationX)**2 + (usersYcordd[j] -baseStationY)**2)**0.5)
```

Enumerate gives two values: index and element of iterable respectively